# Failed to receive SAML response by HTTP post

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml

In SSO Implementation, having validated the User, I created a SAMLResponse object and posted it to the Default Landing URL using IdentityProvider.SendSAMLResponseByHTTPPost() Method.

> IdentityProvider.SendSAMLResponseByHTTPPost(Response,
>   strAssertionConsumerServiceURL, samlResponseXml, relayState);

samlResponseXml - contains the SAML Request XML

On ServiceProvider.ReceiveSAMLResponseByHTTPPost() Method, I am getting the below Catch Exception.

> Failed to receive SAML response by HTTP post

Both the Identity Provider and Service Provider are in same network domain.

Attached the logs for ComponentSpace.SAML2

```
ComponentSpace.SAML2 Verbose: 0 : 9:19:44 PM: Missing form variable SAMLResponse
ComponentSpace.SAML2 Verbose: 0 : 9:19:44 PM: Exception: ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLBindingException: The form is missing the variable SAMLResponse
ComponentSpace.SAML2 Verbose: 0 : 9:19:44 PM: Exception: ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLBindingException: Failed to receive response over HTTP POST. ---> ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLBindingException: The form is missing the variable SAMLResponse
   at ComponentSpace.SAML2.Bindings.HTTPPostBinding.GetFormVariables(HttpRequest httpRequest, String messageFormVariableName, XmlElement& samlMessage, String& relayState)
   at ComponentSpace.SAML2.Bindings.HTTPPostBinding.ReceiveResponse(HttpRequest httpRequest, XmlElement& samlMessage, String& relayState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: You're missing the SAML in the form, look at the error. The form is missing the variable SAMLResponse. The form should contain a hidden field named SAMLRepsponse and posted as a post

Comment: If you use either the browser developer tools or Fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic, you should be able to see what leads up to this error. The most likely cause is an HTTP Get is being received. The SAML response should be sent in an HTTP Post with a SAMLResponse post data.

Comment: In my Assertion Page, while consuming the SAMLResponse by the below method,


`ServiceProvider.ReceiveSAMLResponseByHTTPPost(Request, out samlResponseXml, out relayState);`



I got the Error "Failed to receive SAML response by HTTP post"

@ComponentSpace
However, as per code, it is POST verb, but, Shift+F9 on the *Request object* for System.Web.HttpRequest is been identified as GET. Also, this cannot be changed. If so, Still how could attempt POST over this ?

Comment: You need to identify why you're receiving an HTTP Get. The best way to do this is to capture the network traffic. The identity provider should be sending the SAML response in an HTTP Post. There is no option to receive a SAML response in an HTTP Get. It may be that the HTTP Get originates from your application or some intermediate node rather than the identity provider. Tracing the HTTP traffic will help identify the source.

Comment: @ComponentSpace - After specifying the AssertionConsumer URL as strAssertionConsumerServiceURL = "http://localhost:58986/AssertionInternal";
POST Http VERB was invoked. Able to receive SAML response. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue**:
(1) Failed to receive SAML response by HTTP post

(2)

```
ComponentSpace.SAML2 Verbose: 0 : 9:19:44 PM: Missing form variable SAMLResponse
ComponentSpace.SAML2 Verbose: 0 : 9:19:44 PM: Exception: ComponentSpace.SAML2.SAMLBindingException: The form is missing the variable SAMLResponse
```

**Resolution**:

The log of SAML exception states that the form/format of SAML Response is incorrect.

[Creating SAML Response for SSO](https://mukarrammukhtar.wordpress.com/single-sign-on-p-1/) provides the following sample code to demonstrate how to generate SAML Response using ComponentSpace libray.

```
        // Create a SAML response with the user's local identity.
        private SAMLResponse CreateSAMLResponse()
        {
            //Trace.Write("IdPreating SAML response");
           SAMLResponse samlResponse = new SAMLResponse();
            samlResponse.Destination = strAssertionConsumerServiceURL;
            Issuer issuer = new Issuer(CreateAbsoluteURL("~/"));
            samlResponse.Issuer = issuer;
            samlResponse.Status = new Status(SAMLIdentifiers.PrimaryStatusCodes.Success, null);
            SAMLAssertion samlAssertion = new SAMLAssertion();
            samlAssertion.Issuer = issuer;
            //Subject subject = new Subject(new NameID(User.Identity.Name));
            Subject subject = new Subject(new NameID());
            SubjectConfirmation subjectConfirmation = new SubjectConfirmation(SAMLIdentifiers.SubjectConfirmationMethods.Bearer);
            SubjectConfirmationData subjectConfirmationData = new SubjectConfirmationData();
            subjectConfirmationData.Recipient = strAssertionConsumerServiceURL;
            subjectConfirmation.SubjectConfirmationData = subjectConfirmationData;
            subject.SubjectConfirmations.Add(subjectConfirmation);
            samlAssertion.Subject = subject;
            samlAssertion.SetAttributeValue("MemberId", this.txtMemberId.Text);
            samlAssertion.SetAttributeValue("Name", this.txtName.Text);
            samlAssertion.SetAttributeValue("Phone", this.txtPhone.Text);
            AuthnStatement authnStatement = new AuthnStatement();
            authnStatement.AuthnContext = new AuthnContext();
            authnStatement.AuthnContext.AuthnContextClassRef = new AuthnContextClassRef(SAMLIdentifiers.AuthnContextClasses.Password);
            samlAssertion.Statements.Add(authnStatement);
           samlResponse.Assertions.Add(samlAssertion);
            return samlResponse;
        }
        // Send the SAML response to the SP.
        private void SendSAMLResponse(SAMLResponse samlResponse, string relayState)
        {
            // Serialize the SAML response for transmission.
            XmlElement samlResponseXml = samlResponse.ToXml();
            // Sign the SAML response.
           X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = (X509Certificate2)Application["IdPX509Certificate"];
            SAMLMessageSignature.Generate(samlResponseXml, x509Certificate.PrivateKey, x509Certificate);
          IdentityProvider.SendSAMLResponseByHTTPPost(Response, strAssertionConsumerServiceURL, samlResponseXml, relayState);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After multiple attempts with Firebug Console and Fiddler2, it has been Identified that Http GET was invoked when I tried posting Data to  `AssertionConsumerServiceURL` Page eventhough SendSAMLResponseByHTTPPost() and ReceiveSAMLResponseByHTTPPost() been used.

```
 string strAssertionConsumerServiceURL = "http://localhost:58986/AssertionInternal.aspx";
```

The Above AssertionConsumer Service url was being modified to as below,

```
 string strAssertionConsumerServiceURL = "http://localhost:58986/AssertionInternal";
```

With this URL, the SAML POST Data has been received successfully.

Specifying URL with .aspx extension invoked GET Verb in my application
 rather than POST Verb.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, the assertion consumer service URL you specify must be the correct URL of the endpoint where you call our API to receive the SAML response. The web forms examples use .aspx URLs. The MVC examples use URLs that don't have this extension.

Comment: I had the same problem and removing the .aspx extension from the URL fixed it. The funny thing is that when I point to another Assertion Consumer Service with the same setup, it works without removing the .aspx extension. Both services live in Asp.Net web forms WEBSITE projects. Not MVC nor Web Application. A bug maybe?